# Align footer at bottom of page with fixed html page height

Tags: html, css

I am creating a test certificate using simple html but facing a problem.

The footer is placed just where the screen height ends and not the html height.

[image]

Following is html:

```css
html {
  height: 1366px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 1366px;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

.no-border {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

@media all {
  .page-break {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
    /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;
    /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
  }
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}

.no_left_right {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.no_bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.no_top {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.custom_width {
  width: 5%;
}

.no_borders {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
.footer_table{
   position: absolute;bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width:100%;
   clear:both
 }
```

```html
 

  <div style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;"><b>Company name.</b></div>
   <div style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;">Location</div>
   <hr>
   <div style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;"><b>TEST CERTIFICATE</b></div>
<table style="width:50%;margin-top:5px;" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Coulmn</th>
        <th>Remark</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>LOW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>LOW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>LOW</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="" class="no_left_right no_bottom footer_table footer_table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent";></td>
        <td style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent";></td>
        <td style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent";></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:25%;border:1px solid transparent"></th>
        <th style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent"></th>
        <th style="width:45%;border:1px solid transparent"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:25%;border:1px solid transparent"></th>
        <th style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent"></th>
        <th style="width:45%;border:1px solid transparent"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:25%;border:1px solid transparent">Tested by</th>
        <th style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent">Seal</th>
        <th style="width:45%;border:1px solid transparent">Authorized Signatory</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="" class="no_left_right no_bottom footer_2 footer_table">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3" style="width:65%"><b>TESTED ON <img src="" style="width:10%;margin-bottom:-7px;"> XYZ TESTER</b></th>
        <td style="width:70%;border-left:1px solid transparent;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid black;text-align:left">
            <table style="width:100%;" class="no_borders">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:10%;border:1px solid transparent;text-align:left"><b>Model</b></td>
                    <td style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent;text-align:left"><b>: B 3000-TS</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:70%;border-left:1px solid transparent;border-top:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid black;text-align:left">
            <table style="width:100%;" class="no_borders">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:11%;border:1px solid transparent;text-align:left"><b>Serial No </b></td>
                    <td style="width:20%;border:1px solid transparent;text-align:left"><b>: 11/2017-285</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The things which are bothering me :

**How to keep the footer(s) to bottom of page, with fixed height of html by 1366px ?**

My research :

1) `position` attribute with `fixed` sticks footer to screen bottom which is not what i need. Found `absolute` which looked satisfying but did not worked, `relative` was also used but did not succeed.

2) `display:table` ,`flex` might be useful but not sure how to use it.

[How to stick <footer> element at the bottom of the page (HTML5 and CSS3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976245/how-to-stick-footer-element-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-html5-and-css3)

[How to align footer (div) to the bottom of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525581/how-to-align-footer-div-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

None of the above worked.

Will somebody help me to fix above issues ?

Please note maintaining height of html page by 1366px is necessary / compulsory in this case.

Comment: Can you move the inline style to internal style, then anyone can easily find the issue. Now it's very confusing

Comment: Done please check.

Comment: @Vikrant as you mentioned you used position relative. Can you tell where did you use it?

Comment: I had applied it to css class footer_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should achieve this using css position absolute!
In css do the following change!

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
.footer_table {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and in html, you should have body tag!

```
<body>
  <!--- content here --->

  <table class="footer_table">
    <!--- content here -->
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep the **footer at the bottom of HTML with a fixed height of HTML by 1366px**. Please check the example below.

```css
html {
  height: 1366px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>
    Content box Sample Height 300px.
  </p>

</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h1>
    Footer
  </h1>
</div>
```

An element with **position: absolute;** is positioned **relative** to the nearest **positioned ancestor**. However; if an **absolute positioned** element has **no positioned** ancestors, it uses the **document body**, and moves along with **page scrolling**. For more details **Please read [CSS Layout - The position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)**

Check your code in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rwdo7xa/1/)**

Comment: This answer is correct. Thanks for explanation and snippets. +1

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `bottom:0` or `margin-bottom:0` styles for the footer. specify the height whatever you need.

Comment: As you can see i have already added `bottom:0` for the 2 footer tables and it is not working. Please note height of the whole html should be 1366px and not of the footer.